# How to check for changes in local variable with a time lapse?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to call a function whenever a local  variable has it's value changed.
I tried this code using a while loop but I get locked in the loop.

```
var titleChanged = false;

$scope.$watch('title',function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
        titleChanged = true;
    }
});

while (true) {
    $timeout(checkForChangeAndSave, 3000);
};

function checkForChangeAndSave() {
    if(titleChanged) {
        updateNote();
        titleChanged = false;
    }
}

function updateNote() {
    notesService.update($stateParams.id, {title: $scope.title});
    notesService.getAll();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use the interval service of angular.

The way you implemented it with while will block your code during the timeout execution.

Have a look at the [the angular interval documention](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval).

Answer (score 0):

as I understand that you want to watch for a local variable not (attached to $scope) I may suggest this watch syntax

```
$scope.$watch(function(){return titleChanged;},function(newVal,oldVal){
  // logic goes here
});
```